# changing x in "const int *myPtr = &x"

Tags: c, pointers, constants

In my lecture notes about C pointers I got the following:

```
const int *myPtr = &x; // regular pointer to a const int,

 //x can not be changed through myPtr, but *myPtr yes.
```

Is the last statement correct?

It doesn't make sense to me since `x` and `*myPtr` are the same, aren't they?

If it is correct, what would be an example of that statement?

Comment: The `*` in the comment shouldn't be there. `*myPtr` and `x` designate the same object and  `*myPtr` cannot be used to change it, but `myPtr` itself is modifiable, i.e., it can be made to point to an object other than `x`.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO  This phrase "x can not be changed through myPtr, but *myPtr yes" does not make a sense. The expression *myPtr exactly means through myPtr.:)

Comment: Maybe the comment was supposed to mean "x can not be changed through myPtr, but *myPtr still can change"?

Comment: @ Vlad from Moscow Since x=*myPtr, couldn't I interpreted  "x can not be changed through myPtr, but *myPtr yes" as "x can not be changed through myPtr, but THE POINTED VALUE yes", or "x can not be changed through myPtr, but x yes". After all I am only changing  *myPtr  by x, which are equal. However it feels like the resulting statement is not equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is the last statement correct?*

You can't change `x` through `myPtr`, even if `x` is not `const`. If it means that you can change the pointer itself, in that case it's true because the pointer is not `const`.

If that's the case, the statement is confusing, it would be better if it was `//x can not be changed through myPtr, but myPtr yes...` it's a subtle difference but it changes its meaning.

If *"...but* **myPtr yes"* just means that you can change `x` directly or through a non-const pointer, if `x` is not `const` qualified, well then it would be correct, I wouldn't put it that way, but I guess it's a possible interpretation.

> *It doesn't make sense to me since x and* **myPtr are the same, aren't they?*

They are not the same strictly speaking but `myPtr` is pointing to the memory address where `x` is located, if `x` is `const`, it can't be changed either way, if not it means it can be changed but not through that particular pointer.

Comment: You said I can't change the content of x directly but I did "int x=90; const int *myPtr = &x;  x=x+1; printf("x=%d\n",x);" and I was able to change the content of x directly

Comment: @J.C.VegaO in that code `x` is not const, so you can change it.

Comment: Oh I see what you mena am not using "const int x=90"

Comment: @J.C.VegaO exactly

Comment: I find the statement "int x=90;const int *myPtr = &x "kind of  funny, because the second one implies that myPtr points to a constant int, but int being constant or not  depends on the declaration of x as either int  x=90 or const int x=90. What do you think?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO, it may be useful, `const int *myPtr = &x` means you can't change the underlying variable through that pointer, but you can change it otherwise, provided that it's not `const`, a use case is, for instance, you may have a non const qualified variable that you can change, but you may want to pass a pointer to it to a function and you don't want to allow it to be changed in that particular function.

Comment: All right so "const int *myPtr = &x" doesn't imply that x has to be constant as it may be understood from reading  out loud "const int *myPtr" as "myPtr is a pointer to a constant int". It just means that it can't be changed through that pointer. I was taught to read it like that and it seemed useful , but it is misleading

Comment: @J.C.VegaO, correct. Yes, I see your point, it may be misleading, it reads *pointer to const int*.

Comment: Since x=*myPtr, couldn't I interpret "x can not be changed through myPtr, but *myPtr yes" as "x can not be changed through myPtr, but THE POINTED VALUE yes", or "x can not be changed through myPtr, but x yes". After all I am only changing *myPtr by x, which are equal. However it feels like the resulting statement is not equivalent

Comment: @J.C.VegaO, yes, if you say x directly it's easy to interpret, but if you say *myPtr it's hard to avoid bringing the constness of the pointer to the mix, but you're right it can mean that. I wouldn't put it that way, but I guess it's acceptable.

Comment: why aren't x and *myPtr the same strictly speaking? x is a variable, therefore an alias for a memory address, *myPtr is the content of the memory address myPtr, coincinding with the address of x

Comment: @J.C.VegaO, `myPtr` is a separate variable and has its own memory address in that sense they are not the same, These distinctions are important when answering questions, there are some pro nitpickers around here ;)